# Python Pandas : Change value based on category's highest frequency

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I discovered a categorization error in a dataset I was exploring.

The dataframe looks like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
                     'product': ['ABRICOTS', 'ABRICOTS', 'ABRICOTS', 'ABRICOTS', 'AILS','AILS', 'ANANAS', 'ANANAS', 'ANANAS','ANANAS','ANANAS','ANANAS','ANANAS'], 
                     'family': ['Fruit','Fruit','Fruit', 'Vegetable', 'Vegetable','Vegetable', 'Fruit', 'Fruit','Fruit','Fruit','Cereal','Cereal','Animal Product']
                    })
```

[image]

Each product is supposed to belong to only 1 family category, but using the formula below revealed that I have products with different categories:

```
df1.groupby(['product','family']).size().rename('Freq').reset_index()
```

[image]

Now what I would like to do, is to use a formula to change for each product the family(ies) with the lowest frequency number to the one with the highest in my original dataframe. The expected result would look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use [`Dataframe.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group the dataframe on `product` then use the aggregation function [`Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) to calculate the freq of each `family` category belonging to the product, next create a mapping series `m` by using `groupby` at `level=0` on this series `s` with the aggregation function [`nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nlargest.html) to get the family associated with maximum occurrence for that product, finally use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to map the product to its corresponding family:

```
s = df1.groupby('product')['family'].value_counts()
m = s.groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).nlargest(1).reset_index(level=1, name='freq')
df1['family'] = df1['product'].map(m['family'])
```

Explanation:

```
# print(s)
product   family        
ABRICOTS  Fruit             3
          Vegetable         1
AILS      Vegetable         2
ANANAS    Fruit             4
          Cereal            2
          Animal Product    1
Name: family, dtype: int64

# print(m)
            family  freq
product                  
ABRICOTS      Fruit     3
AILS      Vegetable     2
ANANAS        Fruit     4

# print(df1)
     product     family
0   ABRICOTS      Fruit
1   ABRICOTS      Fruit
2   ABRICOTS      Fruit
3   ABRICOTS      Fruit
4       AILS  Vegetable
5       AILS  Vegetable
6     ANANAS      Fruit
7     ANANAS      Fruit
8     ANANAS      Fruit
9     ANANAS      Fruit
10    ANANAS      Fruit
11    ANANAS      Fruit
12    ANANAS      Fruit
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps,

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
                     'product': ['ABRICOTS', 'ABRICOTS', 'ABRICOTS', 'ABRICOTS', 'AILS','AILS', 'ANANAS', 'ANANAS', 'ANANAS','ANANAS','ANANAS','ANANAS','ANANAS'], 
                     'family': ['Fruit','Fruit','Fruit', 'Vegetable', 'Vegetable','Vegetable', 'Fruit', 'Fruit','Fruit','Fruit','Cereal','Cereal','Animal Product']
                    })
```

Sorting and drop the rows.

```
d=df1.groupby(['product','family']).size().rename('Freq').reset_index().\
             sort_values(['product','Freq'],ascending=False).\
             drop_duplicates('product')[['product','family']]\
             .set_index('product')['family'].to_dict()
```

Get this dict 
[image]

Use map function

```
df1['family'] = df1['product'].map(d)
```

Required output 
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas `groupby` and `transform` functions in combination with the series' `mode` method:

```
df1["family"] = df1.groupby("product")["family"].transform(lambda s: s.mode()[0])
```

Unfortunately we need wrap the mode method in a lambda function here as the mode method returns an array (there might be multiple top candidates) and single values are required. Hence the `s.mode()[0]`. You could also use `s.mode().squeeze()` which will break if there's ambiguity.